# How do I implement deep links in local notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I have so many screens in my application. So when the user taps on the local notification , I'd like to deep-link one of the screens.

The could be not running or active on one of those screens or inactive or suspended state.

I couldn't see how to do that

If anyone could explain it'd be great

Comment: You should know screens before that else you can't navigate. For example you want navigate to Cart screen, Just pass cart items and screen name.

Comment: Could you give me an example code snippet of passing the screen name from notification to app please ?

Comment: Check, added sample code.

Comment: I didn't mean NSNotification .. I meant local and push notification right .. that local notification.

Comment: Edit your question. Still the same process for navigation.

Comment: But how do I know which screen to open for notification , is there any even handler for notification Tap

Comment: You will receive Notification/deep linking payload with key value. You just need to check all those key value and navigate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DeepLinkKit](https://github.com/button/DeepLinkKit) for navigation to different screens. I'm using this library in my app, I have about 30-37 deeplinks for every screen in the app. I'm using this with Cordinators pattern for navigation. Let me know if you need any help with implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in appdelegate or viewcontroller

Implement below methods

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
}
```

This is where you intercept the notification tap and call the appropriate modules either using `OpenURL` or doing a direct push or present or switch the tab of viewcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

1. Send Notification from anywhere.

   ```
   func sendNotification(){
    let info: [String: String] = ["vc_name": "CartViewController"]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("YourLocalNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: info)
   }
   ```
2. Add Notification handler on Receive Notification in your root controller.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.youNotificationAction(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("YourLocalNotification"), object: nil)
    }
   ```

Receive notification, Check your notified information and navigate to your respective controller.

```
    @objc func youNotificationAction(notification: Notification) {
      if let vcName = notification.userInfo?["vc_name"] as? String {
          let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let toVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
          navigationController?.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I am taking about local notification